# Selenium driver.get is slow

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I try to connect to a web page [www.wooclap.com/EPUUJK](http://www.wooclap.com/EPUUJK).
Its a website for create event and ask questions.
At the bottom of the page we can see the users connected.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage')
x =-1

while x <0:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.wooclap.com/EPUUJK")
```

I write this simple code which works and I can see the number of users connected increased by 1 each 5 sec. I would like to improve a lot this speed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Trying disabling the image like this:

```
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Disabling gpu:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

Disabling extensions:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
```

If this doesn't work try asynchronous selenium coding.